# Ajax Webservice call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, cross-domain

I have the below code in my ASPX page to get some data from a webservice. I cannot use WCF so I am using the ASMX and .Net 3.5. However, what I get back is the yellow ASP.net error page talking about setting the web.config error tag to OFF. If I call my method from code behind and response.write it to the page I get a Json string that I have viewed in JSON Viewer and it parses fine. My issue here is the URL format. What am I doing wrong here. Every example I have found uses the webservice.asmx/Method format. I have also added the protocols to my web.config

```
<protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
```

Page Script:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://myserver/mywebservice.asmx/MyMethod',
        dataType: 'jsondata',
        success: function (msg) {
            var table = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th></tr>"
            for (var i = 0; i <= msg.length - 1; i++) {
                var row = "<tr>";
                row += "<td>" + msg[i].ID + "</td>";
                row += "<td>" + msg[i].Title + "</td>";
                row += "</tr>";
                table += row;
            }
            table += "</table>";
            $("#myDiv").html(table);
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("complete");
        }
    });
```

Webservice:

```
    <WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Function MyMethod() As String
    'removed for shorter post
End Function
```

UPDATE: So using the dev tools in Chrome I have found that part of my problem was the server was returning a 403 Forbidden error. After som tweaking I have come up with a partial solution that gives me back my data with json formatting. However, that json formatted text is now wrapped in XML. :-(

I have yet been able to figure out how to get the XML out of my json. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: 'http://myserver/mywebservice.asmx/MyMethod',
dataType: 'jsondata',
```

similar to:

```
contentType: "application/json",
url: '/folderonmyserver/mywebservice.asmx/MyMethod',
dataType: 'json',
data: "{}", // needed for .Net not to blow up sometimes - or send real data
```

and in your success: reference msg.d (or have a translation to isolate that for .Net) given your .net version

```
success: function (msg) {
    var mydata = msg.d;
    var table = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th></tr>"
    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure I follow what your saying. The differences from what I have and what you have is to remove charset=utf-8 and change jsondata to json, right? If so this still does not work.

Comment: and remove the first part of the url to only reference the relative (from your site) location from the page. - and of course isolate the msg.d object that .net produces.

Comment: AND, you have to have some additional settings in .Net 3.5 web.config for it to work- google those or search herein on SO

Comment: well the success function changes aside, I cannot change the URL as this is not local. My webservices run on a completly different server.

Comment: hmm cross domain...try setting `dataType:"jsonp"` = lower case is important here

Comment: some background info here: http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/ and more on specifics here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/